# How can I tell easily that functions have been inlined?

Tags: c++11, optimization

Other than opening a disassembly view, is there any decent mechanism or tool to determine quickly whether LLVM actually inlined methods in a CPP file (i.e., outside the actually class declaration) designated with the 'inline' option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nm` to list the symbols from your program. If the method doesn't show up in the output, it was an `inline` method:

```
nm your_program | grep your_method
```

I tried this solution with `gcc`. For `llvm` you can see this command: [llvm-nm](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-nm.html)

Comment: Note that functions that were inlined don't have to be marked as `inline`.

Comment: Yeah, that is true

Comment: Thanks --- that's a great idea.